# Odoo 13 Web Assets Failure

Tags: nginx, odoo, nginx-reverse-proxy, odoo-12

I have an Odoo instance on a VPS behind a nginx reverse proxy.  When I access the Odoo instance directly at the VPS IP:8069 or domain:8069 then the page is displayed correctly and there are no asset errors.   If I try to access through the proxy, using ip or domain name (default port 80), some javascript resources don't load and/or images are truncated.

nginx.conf

```
user        nobody;
worker_processes   1;
error_log  logs/error.log;
worker_rlimit_nofile 8192;

events {
  worker_connections  4096;  ## Default: 1024
}

http{

  log_format   main '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local]  $status '
    '"$request" $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
  access_log   logs/access.log  main;

  server {
      listen 80;
      server_name www.mysite.com;
      rewrite ^(.*) https://$host$1 permanent;
  }

  server {
     listen 443 ssl http2;
     server_name www.mysite.com;
     proxy_read_timeout 720s;
     proxy_connect_timeout 720s;
     proxy_send_timeout 720s;

     # Add Headers for odoo proxy mode
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
     proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

     #SSL parameters
     ssl on;
     ssl_certificate /etc/mycert/location/fullcert.pem;
     ssl_certificate_key /etc/mycert/location/pkey.pem;
     ssl_session_timeout 30m;
     ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
     ssl_ciphers EECDH+CHACHA20:EECDH+AES128:RSA+AES128:EECDH+AES256:RSA+AES256:EECDH+3DES:RSA+3DES:!MD5;
     ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
     ssl_session_tickets off;

     #log
     access_log /var/log/nginx/odoo.access.log;
     error_log /var/log/nginx/odoo.error.log;

     location ~* / {
       proxy_redirect off;
       proxy_pass http://odoo;
     }

     location /longpolling {
         proxy_pass http://odoo-chat;
     }

      # gzip
      gzip_types text/css text/less text/plain text/xml application/xml application/json application/javascript;
      gzip on;
  }
   upstream odoo {
   server 127.0.0.1:8069;
  }

  upstream odoo-chat {
   server 127.0.0.1:8072;
  }
}
```

I've tried Odoo 12 and 13 with Python 3.6 based on some Python errors that were mentioned in a forum, no change. I have `proxy = true` in my odoo.conf file.

```
2019/10/21 11:56:46 [crit] 2803#0: *1 open() "/var/lib/nginx/tmp/proxy/1/00/0000000001" failed (13: Permission denied) while reading upstream, client: 99.99.254.254, server: www.example.com, request: "GET /web/image/366?access_token=ff2c51a8-716b-448f-98b7-85b97349d39a HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8069/web/image/366?access_token=ff2c51a8-716b-448f-98b7-85b97349d39a", host: "example.com", referrer: "https://example.com/"
```

Comment: Can you check `/var/log/nginx/error.log` and share the errors `nginx` generating?

Comment: researching permissions now, will update when I solve

Comment: ```chown nobody.nobody /var/lib/nginx/tmp/proxy``` has not fixed, will update as I continue

Comment: the files that are denied somewhat change with each refresh so this doesn't seem to be a simple permissions issue

Comment: this is a permissions issue.  If i change the user to root in the nginx.conf file then everything works correctly.  I do not want to leave nginx running as root so I'll investigate more

Answer (score 2):

I experienced this problem just now. This is because nginx is dynamically creating temporary files in `/var/lib/nginx/tmp/proxy` and `chown`-ing will not solve the issue. What I learned was to set [proxy_temp_path](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_temp_path):

1. create a directory wherein user `nobody` has permissions: *e.g.* `mkdir /home/nobody/tmp`
2. Set proxy_temp_path in nginx.config: `proxy_temp_path /home/nobody/tmp 1 2;`

An excerpt of config is shown below:

```
location ~* / {
    proxy_temp_path /home/nobody/tmp 1 2;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://odoo;
}
```